# Creating a new string from entries in a char* array

Tags: c, arrays, char, execvp

So here's my issue.  I have a list of commands inputted from the user that I need to use to pass into `execvp()`.  Here's an example with the `ls` command.

```
char *cmdList = {"ls", "-l", "folder1/folder2"}
```

Now I need a way to modify that first entry so that is has the form "/bin/ls"

Is the only way to do it via the strcat command? Ideally I'd like to directly modify the `ls` entry so I could pass `cmdList` directly into `execvp()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify fullpath to use `execvp()`. So you don't need to worry about modifying the first argument. For example, if you have an array with arguments:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char *cmdList[] = {"ls", "-l", "folder1/folder2", 0};

   execvp(cmdList[0], cmdList);
}
```

`execvp()` will search `ls` in your `PATH` and execute it.

Comment: @purelyp93 note the additional `NULL` pointer element marking the end of the arguments array.

Answer (score 0):

This workes for me.

char *cmdList[]= {"ls", "-l", "folder1/folder2"};

cmdList[0]="/bin/1s";
printf("%s", *cmdList);